# How to loop over dynamically generated input fields?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, local-storage, addeventlistener

I am generating some input fields dynamically on my page, and I want to grab inputs from them to store in localStorage if this way works if not? suggest a way around, how can this be done? also how can i add a event listener to submit button ? followings are code have a look at it and give some suggestions/improvisations.

..

```
HTML
<div id="warnMessage"></div>
<div class="add"></div>
<div class="inputs">
        <input
          type="text"
          maxlength="1"
          id="inputValue"
        />
        <button class="btn" type="button">+</button>
      </div>

javascript

const div = document.querySelector(".add");


const add = document
  .querySelector(".btn")
  .addEventListener("click", addingInps);

function addingInps() {
  const inputValue = parseInt(document.getElementById("inputValue").value);

  if (isNaN(inputValue)) {
    document.getElementById("warnMessage").innerText = "Enter Again";
    document.getElementById("inputValue").value = "";
  } else {
    const form = document.createElement("form");
    form.method = "post";
    form.action = "#";

    for (let i = 0; i < inputValue; i++) {

      const inp = document.createElement("input");
      inp.type = "text";
      inp.maxLength = "12";
      inp.required = true;
      inp.className = "inp";

      const br = document.createElement("br");

      
      form.appendChild(br.cloneNode());
      form.appendChild(inp);
      form.appendChild(br.cloneNode());

      div.appendChild(form);
      document.querySelector("#inputValue").style.display = "none";
    }

    const sub = document.createElement("button");
    sub.className = "subButton";
    sub.type = "button";
    sub.value = "button";
    sub.textContent = "Submit"
    form.appendChild(sub);

  }
}
```

Comment: Assign class to dynamic `<input>` nodes (with [`.classList.add()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)) and query them, when needed with [`Document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName).

Answer (score 0):

You are loop through an input ...not an array or nodelist.
It cant work

Comment: how to make it work? as i want to grab inputs from them.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier if you appended an ID with every new input field you made

```
for(let i=0;i < inputValue;i++){
   // create your element ipt
   ipt.setAttribute("id","autogenerated_" + i);
}
```

and grab value based on id

```
document.getElementById("autogenerated_x").value();
```

about setting an event listener, I can't think any other way of the classic

```
btn.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    // your functionality
});
```

Comment: thanks it worked now i have to grab values from them how can i do it, is looping over them works?

Comment: @prph8 : Actually, having such *autogenerated* id's doesn't make any sense at all. As long as you treat those inputs as a bulk in uniform way, using `class` attribute as a distinct feature (as I suggested in my initial comment) makes way more sense. So, once you need values of those elements, you simply do `const dynamicInputValues = [...document.getElementsByClassName(/* common class name */)].map(({value}) => value)`

Comment: Yes, you loop the same way you created them. I guess you are gonna do it in your eventListener function

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov The only reason I am recommending Ids is because in a form you need to parse inputs differently sometimes. two inputs may be strings and a third may be a number. In that case, you need to know at which input field you are referring to

Comment: @PanosSavvaidis i think i m gonna assign them class names as these inputs will only take strings and there will be another set of inputs taking numbers only,

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov can you be more specific on getting values from inputs, please.

Comment: @PanosSavvaidis : regardless of what type you think your data is, `.value()` will return the string